# How do I update value of my Secret created in Azure Key Vault using .Net SDK

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I added a connection string in my KeyVault Secret. I wanted to update the same using .Net SDK but not able to find any method that will allow me to do so.

I tried using `UpdateSecretAsync()` but this method doesn't accept Secret Value.

Can someone please point me to correct method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `SetSecretAsync` method.  If the secretName doesn't exists it will create it.  If it does exist it will replace it.

```
// Code to generate a new secret
var newSecret = "<the new secret>"

// Update the secret in the key vault
client.SetSecretAsync(vault, secretName, newSecret);
```

Comment: Not to be confused with UpdateSecretAsync which seems to be more about metadata properties, like tags, and valid from/to dates, rather than values of the secret themselves.

Answer (score -1):

```
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

namespace key_vault_console_app
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var kvUri = $"https://{your keyvault name}.vault.azure.net";

            var client = new SecretClient(new Uri(kvUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());

            var secretValue = client.GetSecret("Vishwa-Test");

            Console.WriteLine(secretValue.Value.Value);

            client.SetSecret("Vishwa-Test", "Test1234");
        }
    }
}
```